# How make tcp connection in python to retrieve call logs from PBX without telnet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, netcat, pbx

Can any one Help me to make tcp connection in python to retrieve call logs from PBX without telnet ?? 
The Old way I used in terminal is :
-note that 192.168.1.101 is my PBX ip and 5289 is the port i use

## telnet 192.168.1.101 5289

SMDR\n
ENTER THE PASSWORD: 12345

########## calls log com up here

I need another way < because I Heared that telnet is not recommended to this operation ,, 
Note ... I need the solution as a script in python ...
I tried a socket package but it doesn't work with me (it is just open a chat box between me and pbx 
just like the output of the command

## nc 192.168.1.101 5289

,and Not let me to retrieve call logs),, may be i missing some thing .
 note that it worked  with me in terminal like that :

## stty raw && nc 192.168.1.101 5289 && stty sane

-sSmMdDrR
-Enter Password: 1122334455

########## calls log com up here

..but i want to make this thing as a script in python with socket or anything else , please !!

Comment: You might want to look at https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/